# Scroll Page to top onClick of a button in Saleforce1

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system, javascript-controller, scrolling

I have a problem scrolling to the top of a lightning component page in Salesforce1. I have tried using

1. window.scrollTo(0,0);
2. Added the below attribute in the button tag

   > oncomplete="window.scrollTo('Top',0,0);"
3. Putting the component inside a ui:wrapperScroller and calling the method 
   component.find('auraIdOfuiwrapper').scrollTo('Top',0,0);

But none of them seems to work. Below Code

## Component

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction">
  <ui:scrollerWrapper class="slds-scrollable" aura:id="scrollerTop">
     <div aura:id="homePage" class="slds-scrollable" >
       <br/>
       <br/>
       <br/>
       <br/>
       <br/>
       <br/>
       <br/>
       <br/>
       <br/>
       <br/>
       <br/>
     </div>
     <button type="button" aura:id="nextButtonWSP"  onclick="{!c.top}" oncomplete="window.scrollTo('Top',0,0);" >Top</button>
  </ui:scrollerWrapper>
 </aura:component>
```

## Controller

```
top: function(component, event, helper){
    component.find('scrollerTop').scrollTo('Top',0,0);
      /*
      scrollTo('Top',0,0);
     */
},
```

And as per the Salesforce article on ui:scrollerWrapper this method is supported. IS this a Salesforce bug ? And if so, is there a workaround available ?

Comment: `window.scrollTo('Top',0,0);` won't work due to the locker service. Did you try it without defining `oncomplete`? btw. syntax would be `window.scrollTo(0, 0);`

Comment: Yes.. I have tried both.. same problem..

Comment: just updated my answer.

Answer (score 5):

The propper syntax for `scrollTo` according to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_scrollerWrapper.htm):

```
scrollTo('custom', 0, 0);
or
scrollTo('top');
```

I reproduced it, called the methods as documented and was also not able to scroll to top, I guess it's just another feature that is not working properly.

after some more research, I found out the following works:

```
top: function(component, event, helper){
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
},
```

So we still seem to have access to the window object, I found [some more details](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_lightning_locker.htm):

> Restrictions to Global References
>       LockerService applies restrictions to global references. You can access intrinsic objects, such as Array. LockerService provides secure
>   versions of non-intrinsic objects, such as window. The secure object
>   versions automatically and seamlessly control access to the object and
>   its properties.

Comment: Thanks..It works in desktop but my problem is specific to mobile devices and there are some restrictions in using native scroller methods.

Answer (score 2):

The below code worked for me.

```
var scrollOptions = {
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
            behavior: 'smooth'
        }
        window.scrollTo(scrollOptions);
```

Here is the reference to [scrollOptions documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScrollToOptions)

Thanks!