# Aura component - Page scrolls back to the user clicked section

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript-controller, scrolling

There is a custom Aura component at bottom of a page, user clicks a menu item in the custom component and a toast is shown along with the tab user needs to work at the top of the page, when toast is shown - the page scrolls up properly and the message is shown along with the tab he needs to work on, immediately the page scrolls back to the custom component at bottom of the page and user has to manually scroll back up to proceed with his work.

Looks like going back to the section that originated the event is the standard behavior of Aura components, I tried the options mentioned here in [Scroll Page to top onClick of a button in Saleforce1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/197200/scroll-page-to-top-onclick-of-a-button-in-saleforce1/297266#297266) - in render or afterrender events or at the end of the custom component logic, but did not work.

How to stop the standard SF behavior of scrolling back down or how to identify that the component logic is done and where to write the logic for scrolling back up? Any suggestions will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue before and was able to overcome the issue by setting the mode of the Toast message to "pester" like below.

```
 component.find('notifLib').showToast({ 
                "title": "Error!",  
                "message": "test error.",   
                "variant": "error", 
                "mode" : "pester"   
            });
```

Comment: It worked in one scenario, but not working in another! Does it have any limitation with respect to the nesting of enqueue actions as  that is the only difference between both scenarios?